# LINQ Lists Logic

Tags: c#, linq, list, console

I am new to LINQ. I just want to ask a question regarding the usage of LINQ.

The situation is that I have 2 Players. Given is Player1 and Player2. Both of them consist of TeamName (string) and a score (int).

I made a list for Player 1,

```
public static List<Player1> play1 = new List<Player1>
    {
        new Player1 { TeamName = "Manchester United", Score = 1 },
        new Player1 { TeamName = "Arsenal", Score = 1 },
        new Player1 { TeamName = "Manchester United", Score = 3 },
        new Player1 { TeamName = "Liverpool", Score = 2 },
        new Player1 { TeamName = "Swansea", Score = 2 }
    };
```

And another list for Player2

```
public static List<Player2> play2 = new List<Player2>
    {
        new Player2 { TeamName = "Chelsea", Score = 0 },
        new Player2 { TeamName = "Manchester United", Score = 1 },
        new Player2 { TeamName = "Fulham", Score = 1 },
        new Player2 { TeamName = "Manchester United", Score = 1 },
        new Player2 { TeamName = "Manchester United", Score = 4 }
    };
```

So what I did next is to create a List for game which is this:

```
public static List<Game> game = new List<Game>
    {

    };
```

But I am clueless on what I am going to do next.

My code for LINQ is

```
IEnumerable<Game> x = from games in game
                               select games;
```

What I want achieve is I want to get how many times Manchester United won, lose, draw and it's total score. But I am so clueless for what I am going to do next. I don't even know if I am doing it right.

I am looking for any suggestion if what I am doing is right and how I am going to solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you create two classes of players `Player1` and `Player2`? It looks like bad design. I propose you create a class `Player` that has Man. United, Arsenal, etc. and then you create a `Game` object that has references to the two players together with the score.

Comment: What does your `Player` class represent? Why does it have a score? What are you trying to achieve, what are you trying to model? Let's start from gathering and analyzing requirements.

Comment: how do you count number of times a team has won or lost?

Comment: You should have single type of player/team then in the Game class, you will have two teams, their scores and calculated winning Field.

Comment: Because I want to compare the 1st game which is MU vs Chelsea, determine their scores, who lost and who won then proceed to the next game which is Arsenal VS MU and do the same thing. Am I doing it wrong? What do you guys think?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define the game data structure.

From what I do see - there a multiple ways to implement most things ... but I think in this case we want to change the design a bit.

Instead of player let's have a team and a game objects.
A team has a name (and maybe possibly list of games).
A game consist of two teams and a game result.

Let's have something like

```
    private class Team
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    private class Game
    {
        public Team Team1 { get; set; }
        public Team Team2 { get; set; }

        public GameResult Result { get; set; }
    }

    enum GameResult
    {
        Team1Won,
        Draw,
        Team2Won
    }
```

In addition we can define the result from the team perspective

```
    enum TeamResultInAGame
    {

        TeamLost = 0,
        Draw = 1,
        TeamWon = 3,
    }
```

Then we can get the team result using a linq query like

```
        var teamResults = from game in games
                    where game.Team1.Name == relevantTeam || game.Team2.Name == relevantTeam
                    let teamWon = (game.Team1.Name == relevantTeam && game.Result == GameResult.Team1Won) ||
                                  (game.Team2.Name == relevantTeam && game.Result == GameResult.Team2Won)
                    let draw = game.Result == GameResult.Draw
                    select teamWon ? 
                           TeamResultInAGame.TeamWon :
                           draw ? TeamResultInAGame.Draw : TeamResultInAGame.TeamLost;
```

A full example:

```
        Team manchester = new Team() { Name = "Manchester" };
        Team chelsea = new Team() { Name = "Chelsea" };
        Team arsenal = new Team() { Name = "Arsenal" };

        List<Game> games = new List<Game>();
        games.Add(new Game() { Team1 = manchester, Team2 = chelsea, Result = GameResult.Draw });
        games.Add(new Game() { Team1 = arsenal, Team2 = manchester, Result = GameResult.Team1Won });
        games.Add(new Game() { Team1 = chelsea, Team2 = arsenal, Result = GameResult.Draw });
        games.Add(new Game() { Team1 = chelsea, Team2 = manchester, Result = GameResult.Draw });

        string relevantTeam = manchester;

        var teamResults = from game in games
                    where game.Team1.Name == relevantTeam.Name || game.Team2.Name == relevantTeam.Name
                    let teamWon = (game.Team1.Name == relevantTeam.Name && game.Result == GameResult.Team1Won) ||
                                  (game.Team2.Name == relevantTeam.Name && game.Result == GameResult.Team2Won)
                    let draw = game.Result == GameResult.Draw
                    select teamWon ? 
                           TeamResultInAGame.TeamWon :
                           draw ? TeamResultInAGame.Draw : TeamResultInAGame.TeamLost;

        Console.WriteLine("Wins Count: " + teamResults.Count(result => result == TeamResultInAGame.TeamWon));
        Console.WriteLine("Lost count: " + teamResults.Count(result => result == TeamResultInAGame.TeamLost));
        Console.WriteLine("Draw count: " + teamResults.Count(result => result == TeamResultInAGame.Draw));
        Console.WriteLine("Total score: " + teamResults.Sum(result => (int)result));
```